# DB2 procedure compilation from KSH script

Tags: db2, ksh

I am writing a KSH script to accept a .sql file parameter followed by each schema that file is to be compiled in. The script assumes the .sql file is a DB2 9.7 procedure.

I believe I am stuck on the syntax of the db2 command for the termination character. We always use the at symbol ('@'), however the following snippet fails with error "DB21001E  The option "-@" specified after the 'db2' command or in the DB2OPTIONS variable is incorrect." Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/ksh
. $IBM_DB_DIR/db2profile
db2 connect to dwdev3
const_compil_string_suffix="-vtd@ -f ../../stored_procedures/"
script_name="ETL.THING.sql"
db2 "$const_compil_string_suffix$script_name"
db2 terminate
```

I have confirmed that the resulting string command above the 'terminate' does work at linux prompt compiling the procedure as expected:
    db2 -vtd@ -f ../../stored_procedures/ETL.THING.sql

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try losing the quotation marks:

```
db2 ${const_compil_string_suffix}${script_name}
```

Comment: mustaccio - you are completely right. Thank you, simply removing those quotation marks as stated works perfectly. Sorry I asked a question that was so easy to solve - I should have tested that beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the option string `-vtd@` might be the culprit.

When using single character options most unix command accept two types of options, those with and those without arguments.

Apparently the `@` character is being processed as an option argument, however the error message indicates it is seen as an option on its own.

Try separating the options, as in: `-v -t -d@`, reorder them. or remove one of the `-t` or `-v` options.

Beware though. I have no knowledge about the `db2` cli. Experiment at your own risk.

Was the -t option added later?

Comment: The combination `-vtd@` is perfectly valid. `-d@` is not valid without `-t`. The problem is in the command line parsing - when you quote the options, as in `db2 "-vtd@ ..."` the DB2 CLI has hard time figuring out what is what.

Comment: Henk Langeveld - thank you for your suggestion. IBM'd DB2 is rather fussy on the input parameters, as mustaccio says, the syntax used was valid, just the wrapper of double quotes was not.